# Why do apps from the play store get moved back to internal storage after update

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, system-apps

I've got a good amount of apps installed on my phone's *internal storage* and I've moved the majority of them (anything taking up more than 15MB) to my *SD card*. My Android version is *Lollipop* now. After each update they get moved back to my device's *internal storage*, but In older versions of Android they would stay on the *SD card*.

Would it be possible to force the apps to stay on the *SD card* even after they update? Or is the only way to stop them from moving to never update them?

Answer (score 0):

If it's system applications then what ever you update or download will be automatically moved to internal storage. 
If it's not the reason then check your play store storage.